# Change my way of getting JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I was wondering if I could change the way I am getting my JSON object.

Right now I'm using,

```
JSONObject d = jsonarray.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(xyz)-1);
String id = d.getString(TAG_ID); 
uid.setText(id);
```

The way I'm parsing my `jsonobject` from my database right now, is as follows, User enters an id and my jsonparser looks for this id, except that I want to id to be a string instead of an integer. Since the value it searches for holds irregular and special signs. The numbers it needs to be able to parse are Code-39 symbol/format. It will be used in junction with barcode scanning..

Since `getJSONObject(int)` renders in int, I was wondering if you guys knew a way for me to change the type of the getjsonobject.. Or another way around.. Since the way it is parsing now I can only use regular numbers..

---

**EDIT** For code

```
}
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayMessageActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        String xyz = edt.getText().toString();


        try {    // Getting JSON Array


            user = json.getJSONObject(TAG_TAG);
            JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(xyz);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String fname = c.getString(TAG_FIRST_NAME);
            String lname = c.getString(TAG_LAST_NAME);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String ipa = c.getString(TAG_IP);
            String country = c.getString(TAG_COUNTRY);
            //Set JSON Data in TextView
            uid.setText(id);
            name1.setText(fname);
            name2.setText(lname);
            email1.setText(email);
            ipaddres.setText(ipa);
            cou.setText(country);




public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried using gson?

Comment: where is your jsonarray coming from and how does it relate to your database ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you must use an int is that you're working with a `JSONArray`. By definition, it uses a zero-based incremental int as the index. To get an item with a specific property (such as "id"), you'd have to parse the whole array first, and then iterate through the values until you find the object with the desired id property.

Instead of using an array, you could make each item a normal `JSONObject`, like this:

```
{
    "items": {
        "-1": {},
        "+1": {},
        "00": {}
    }
}
```

This way, each item is a property of the items object and can be accessed using its string id:

```
JSONObject items = json.getJSONObject("items");
JSONObject myItem = items.getJSONObject(xyz);
```

Comment: So what your saying, is that when i try to parse the json not as an array but as an object alone, i would be able to include specific characters in my json parsing sample? Lets say, all of these 0-9,A-Z,-(dash),.(dot),$(dollar-sign),/(forward-slash),+(plus-sign),%(percent-sign) and a space?

Could you also clear something up for me? Im using the parseInt or parseLong function, but since integers cannot use the weird typeface im trying to get, what would the string version of my parsing look like? As there is no parseString method?

Comment: My suggestion requires changing the structure of your JSON data (from an array to a normal object). You would not need to parse the string identifier because the "index" of each item would already be a string in this case.

Comment: Hey, i changed the json array to jsonobject, except the fact that i ask for the json my using the parseInt function, do you have any idea what i could use to make it check for any value and make it return so?

Comment: Update your question with your current JSON / code and I will take a look.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question. What exactly does it need to do? Also, an example of your JSON structure would be helpful.

Comment: Initially im using the json parser to get the info which was entered in the edittext.. The id entered should match an id in my json db, and return all the values in it.. Now here comes the tricky part, the ids are made up of numbers like these 3 examples: 111.111.111 and 123.ABC.123 and ADB1993.. At first i was using the JSONObject, and getJSONObject, with a parseInt function to make it look up those ids, entered in my edittext.

Comment: And did you change the format of the JSON sent from your server to an object instead of an array?